# list of anonymous pipes in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, redirect, pipe

Consider an array of compressed files.

```
array=(a.jpg.gz b.jpg.gz c.jpg.gz)
```

The uncompressed data needs to be passed to an application without the use of temporary files or the hassle of named pipes.

If each compressed stream could be passed by simple concatenation to the previous, then the task is easy, but some application calls require distinct files passed as distinct arguments.

For example, this application naturally processes three distinct, uncompressed files:

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg output.jpg
```

How might one capture equivalent functionality using the array of compressed files? Note of course that the size as well as the contents of the array is dynamic.

One might try:

```
convert $(for a in ${array[@]}; do echo <(gunzip -c < $a); done) output.jpg
```

Then one will see a message, depending on the application, similar to:

```
/dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

Some ugly alternatives might be considered:

```
$SHELL -c "convert $(for a in ${array[@]}; do echo -n \<\(gunzip -c < $a\)\ ; done) output.jpg"
```

Is a better solution available?

Comment: It's not the subshell; process substitutions just aren't persistent, and you can't save the resulting file names in an array. `for x in foo bar baz; do a+=(<(echo "$x")); done; cat "${a[@]}"` also fails.

Comment: (Also, the command you show doesn't process three input files; it processes the first two and produces `output-1.jpg` and `output-2.jpg`.)

Comment: Valid points. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: FWIW `convert` itself seems to require that the input file has the proper extension, so if that's the program in question, you're in a pickle.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly the same as your last idea, of generating the command line to pass to `bash -c`. It makes use of `printf`'s internal loop, rather than using a `for` loop. It is, I think, robust against any legal file name that `array` might contain.

```
bash -c $'convert $(printf \'<(gunzip -c < %q) \' "$@" ) ' _ "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Why `bash -c` vs `eval` here?

Comment: I didn't give the matter any thought; just simplifying what the OP already had.

Comment: I am accustomed to using subshells, but I have no reason why `eval` is not cleaner, faster, and otherwise better.